# How to select name/value pair in Select-Object?

Tags: windows, powershell

To check assemblies' digital signature, I use Windows PowerShell `Get-AuthenticodeSignature`.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.*.dll" -Recurse |
    Get-AuthenticodeSignature |
    Select-Object -Property Path, Status,
        @{Name='SubjectName';Expression={($_.SignerCertificate.Subject)}}
```

The output field SubjectName has too many name/value pairs:

```
Path                                                                                                    Status SubjectName
----                                                                                                    ------ -----------
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll             NotSigned
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll        NotSigned
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll                Valid CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll     Valid CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=MOPR, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
```

How can I reduce the output to just a single value: "Microsoft Corporation"?
The output I would like to have is a CSV like this:

```
Path,Status,SubjectName
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll,NotSigned,
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll,NotSigned,
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll,Valid,Microsoft Corporation
C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll,Valid,Microsoft Corporation
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using a small helper function to parse out the issuer name from the X500DistinghuishedName:

```
function Get-IssuerName([string]$IssuerDN) {
    # helper function to parse the name out of the X500DistinghuishedName formatted 'Issuer' string
    if ($IssuerDN -match 'O=([^,]+)') { $matches[1] }
    elseif ($IssuerDN -match 'CN=([^,]+)')  { $matches[1] }
    else { $IssuerDN }
}
```

Then, in your Select statement use it like:

```
Select-Object -Property Path, Status,
    @{Name='SubjectName';Expression={(Get-IssuerName $_.SignerCertificate.Subject)}}
```

Comment: Create function, means I cannot run it in command line? Need to execute a CMD file?

Comment: @MichaelG this is PowerShell, no cmd.. Simply put the function on top and there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the undesired parts of the subject in your calculated property:

```
@{n='SubjectName', e={$_.SignerCertificate.Subject -replace ',.*' -replace '^CN='}}
```

Comment: It works! Can you suggest how to convert this output to CSV?

Comment: @MichaelG Just pipe the output to `Export-Csv`, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up:

1. Use the `function Get-IssuerName`
2. Execute the script line using the `Get-IssuerName` in the `Select-Object` statement
3. Pipe the output to `Export-Csv`

Here's the script:

```
function Get-IssuerName([string]$IssuerDN) {
    # helper function to parse the name out of the X500DistinghuishedName formatted 'Issuer' string
    if ($IssuerDN -match 'O=([^,]+)') { $matches[1] }
    elseif ($IssuerDN -match 'CN=([^,]+)')  { $matches[1] }
    else { $IssuerDN }
}

Get-ChildItem -File -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.*.dll" -Recurse |
    Get-AuthenticodeSignature |
    Select-Object -Property Path, Status, 
        @{Name='SubjectName';Expression={(Get-IssuerName $_.SignerCertificate.Subject)}} |
        Export-Csv -Path d:\temp\AuthenticodeSignature.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image: PowerShell]

And the resulting CSV output:

```
"Path","Status","SubjectName"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.Expression.Drawing.dll","NotSigned",""
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll","NotSigned",""
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll","Valid","Microsoft Corporation"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll","Valid","Microsoft Corporation"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll","Valid","Microsoft Corporation"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll","Valid","Microsoft Corporation"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\My Product\Components\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll","Valid","Microsoft Corporation"
```

Voilà! Many many thanks to @"Ansgar Wiechers" and @Theo